# What is a proper verb for appending items to a resource in REST API?

Tags: restful-architecture, api-design

My resource URL looks like this: `/container/:id`

I need an API to append items to a container, so I come up with something like `/container/:id/items`, now what should be the verb? POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes POST is correct here. It is used when creating new resources. An item in a container is a resource.

Say your container is a chat, and items are chat messages,

POST to `/chat/:id/messages` makes perfect sense.

Comment: Thx. Do you happen to know of some public APIs that I can take as an example?

Comment: @satoru yeah check here under create new repository https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/